# Debugger error 193 lazarus

Tags: windows, debugging, lazarus, freepascal

I can't debug one of my programs for a year now. When I press the green Run button, the following error message appears:

[image]

The full text is:

```
The GDB command:
"-exec-run"
returned the error:
",msg="Error creating process C:/Users/leven/OneDrive/J\341t\351kpogramok/People/people.exe, (error 193).""
```

I've read many forums about this error, but my case looks a bit different...

1. As you can see, the file's path doesn't include any characters that could occur this problem (no spaces, no special letters). I've tried running outside OneDrive, same error.
2. I've spent a lot of time looking for something in my program that occurs this error and found that if I delete some parts of it (eg. a few procedures or functions, which contains a lot of code though), the program is debuggable again! So the trouble is with some parts of the program, but I still don't know the exact problem.
3. As I can remember, I've always debugged this program in a 64bit OP.
4. The one thing that could be problematic is that I probably started writing the program using Windows 7 or 8, and now I want to run it using Windows 10, but I still don't understand, why deleting some parts of the program is a solution...

Thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE:**

I've found, that the line

```
p[x,y,2,1]:=r;
```

cannot be debugged by the compiler. 
Description:

```
p: array [1..15000, 1..10000, 1..7, 1..4] of integer;
```

p[] is a game field. The first two parameters are coordinates, the third and the fourth are not important.

x, y and r are integers.

So, the command seen above writes a number into the game field (p[]) array using the x, y coordinates.

Comment: What anti-virus s/ware are you using on your PC, and do you get the same problem if you turn it off?  And can you debug a simpler app on your PC?

Comment: The only anti-virus on my PC is the windows defender. I've tried to turn off app & browser control, but nothing has changed. I can perfectly run and debug other free-pascal programs, even larger ones. Only this one project can't work. The same error occurs on my notebook and on other PCs I've already run the program.

Comment: But what about if you turn Windows Defender off:  do you still get the debugger error then?

Comment: It's totally turned off, but I get the same error.

Comment: I was asking about A/V s/ware in case the problem code was giving your app a signature the A/V s/ware reacts to.  Next:  Does the problem code contain any `Initialization` sections?

Comment: Btw, are you the "Mr Albert" who was writing in this thread http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=35333.0http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=35333.0 with the same problem?  I'm asking because there was a point which came up in that thread which could be important.

Comment: No, I only used procedures, functions and variable declarations.

Comment: Yes, I am Mr Albert there :) Which part is useful there? Because I've tried everything they've said there and none of them solved the problem.

Comment: well, it was the simple question of whether your application starts when you try to start it as a normal application, that is directly from Windows, rather than via the Lazarus debugger, GDB.Exe.  F.i. if you navigate to your app via Windows Explorer and double-click it (or use `Open` from the right-mouse context menu), does it start or not?

Comment: Yeah, the .exe works well, I only can't modify it with debugging the code again if some parts of the original code are not removed or transformed into comments with // or {}. There's something wrong with these specific parts, but they are too long to find out the problem with them.

Comment: Ok, find out where GDB.Exe is located - it will be somewhere under your Lazarus folder.  Then navigate to that folder in a Windows CMD prompt window and start GDB manually.  It will tell you its version.  What is it?

Comment: Ok, it's at C:\lazarus\mingw\x86_64-win64\bin and if I'm not wrong, it's version is 7.3.50.20110510-cvs.

Comment: Sorry if this is getting a bit like the "twenty questions"game, but these qs are trying to eliminate various possible causes.  Next q: Do you have Lazarus's compile target set to 64-bits and, if so, can you compile and run your app under the debugger with the compile target set to 32-bits?

Comment: I can only say thank you for your many questions :D I put a tick in the box "Win32 gui application (-WG)" (it was empty), but nothing has changed, same error message.

Comment: Well, we're running out of possibilities.  I suspect what is happening is that when the debugger tries to get Windows to load your program, there is a problem with one of the DLLs your app depends on.  Simple question first:  Does the code you need to comment out to get debugging to work make any external calls to the OS (or external libraries, OLE objects, etc), or does it only call other parts of your code?

Comment: Let me check the whole out-commented code, it will take a while...

Comment: I've made an update to the question including a line of the code which can't be debugged. It may help a bit.

Comment: Well done.  I'll take a look at that tomorrow.  Meanwhile maybe someone else will be able to spot the problem - I wouldn't be surprised if it is to do with the size of the array `p`.  If it is (try experimenting with much lower values of the first two bounds), then a work-around might be to use a "sparse array" library (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix, which refers to a sparse matrix but it's the same thing).

Comment: If I use your declaration of `p`, then the app compiles and starts under the debugger, **but** I get a `SIGSEGV` exception as the app executes `p[x, y, 1,1] := r` with x & y equal to 100 and r = 666.

Comment: Bingo! the p[] was too huge for the memory, I changed it to "p: array [1..1000, 1..1000, 1..7, 1..4] of shortint" and everything works well!!! Now I just need to figure out how to work with a smaller field in order not to cause problems like this again. Thank you so much for your time and help! Please write an answer to the question and I will mark it as an answer. :)

Comment: That cannot be the reason. If it were, it would also fail when not run under a debugger, which you explicitly stated would run as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we established through a series of queries in comments that the necessary and sufficient condition to provoke the debugger problem you've been getting is to include in your app the declaration of the array `p` that you've added to your q, that is:

```
var
  p: array [1..15000, 1..10000, 1..7, 1..4] of integer;
```

For you, it seems that just including this declaration in your code is sufficient to make the debugger throw the error you quote.

For me the debugger starts fine but I get a SIGSEGV error on the assignment to `p[]` in the following code:

```
var
  p: array [1..15000, 1..10000, 1..7, 1..4] of integer;
  x,
  y,
  r : integer;

begin
  x := 100;
  y := 100;
  r := 666;
  p[x, y, 1, 1] := r;
  writeln('Press any key ...');
  readln;
end.
```

So, I would try smaller values for the first two bounds of the `p` array.  If that works and you still need the original bounds, I would suggest looking for an FPC library which implements "sparse arrays" and declare `p` as one of those.

Good luck!

Comment: Well, the array is ~16.8 GB in size. I guess that is a problem for almost any debugger (and most runtimes anyway). If it is a local array, even more.